# How do I determine what impact upgrading Management Framework may have?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I was on one of our web servers earlier today testing something, when I wanted to get into PowerShell. I got in and did what I wanted, but I discovered that PowerShell on this server is version 2. So I asked one of our system administrators if he could put a more recent version of PowerShell onto the server. He said that the version of Management Framework is older and would need to be upgraded in order to install a newer version of PowerShell. I'm a developer, not a sys admin, so I'm taking his word for it. He asked me to test and determine what impact upgrading Management Framework would have. This web server has 2 web sites on it. A third party website and a small MVC web app I wrote, so I don't have a lot of apps to check. I just don't know how to go about it. Would appreciate help, please.

Comment: This is what a Dev and QA environment is for. Hopefully you have both. If not, spin up a clone or P2V of the server and test with that.

Comment: Also it would be difficult to predict what type of issues will be encountered after upgrade, since you have your own environment. that does not essentially mean  there could be issues..may be there is or or isn't.  if you are not sure, best way to try it on a replica/uat environment as its already suggested